# TypeError: Cannot read property 'salt' of undefined | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, server, undefined, salt

I created by app backend in nodejs, when i run my server it gives me this error

[image]

it was working well, yesterday, but it is giving me this error.

here is the snap of routes/login.js 29:34 line

[image]

please help me if anyone know how to fix it.